# Control of type 'HtmlEditorExtender' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, itext

I have have a panel on my webform, within this panel i have lots of stuff along with

**Button Click**

```
protected void btntopdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditorExtender extender = (AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditorExtender)Panel1.FindControl("HtmlEditorExtender1");
            Panel1.Controls.Remove(extender);

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            Panel1.RenderControl(hw); // error over here
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
        }
```

**ERROR:**

```
Control 'ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_HtmlEditorExtender1' of 
type 'HtmlEditorExtender' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

**Webform:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
  //lot of stuff in between
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtkeyresultforyear"
                            EnableSanitization="false">
                        </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
  //lot of stuff in between
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I see you have master page there, can you confirm if `ContentPlaceHolder` is inside `<form runat="server">` in your master page?

Comment: I have master page within master page , the outermost master page has the scripmanager  which is well within` <form runat="server">`

Answer (score 0):

Then, you need to use the `ScriptManagerProxy` on any nested master pages or content pages.

**ScriptManagerProxy class enables nested components such as content pages and user controls to add script and service references to pages when a ScriptManager control is already defined in a parent element.**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295370.aspx

Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy(v=vs.110).aspx) for ScriptmanagerProxy class reference

**UPDATE**

In addition to that, you need to override `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform.aspx

Comment: I added `ScriptManagerProxy` on my page, same issue.

Comment: The top-most master page should have the ScriptManager, and the other master pages/content pages should have a ScriptManagerProxy. Have you done all those?

Comment: right now the top most master page has scripmanager,  the child masterpage has proxy scriptmanager, the page which uses this child masterpage also has proxy scriptmanager. Same issue. :(